# ¿Por qué cambia el entorno visual cuando creo una interfaz en Java?

Tags: java, java-ee, netbeans-8.2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
package Principal;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class interactividad extends javax.swing.JFrame {

 public interactividad() {
    initComponents();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}
private void jButton2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    int opcion;
    opcion = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Desea salir del programa ?");
    if (opcion == 0) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

**¿Qué instrucción debo poner para que la interfaz me quede como la que esta hacia la derecha y no como la izquierda, que esta toda cuadrada?**

Comment: swing es asi como el de la izquierda , la derecha parece javafx(ojo parece) , talvez este enlace te ayude un poco https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234850/customize-joptionpane-dialog

Comment: Creo que @Carlos tiene razón puede que el de la derecha este programado con JavaFX y no con SWING, también puede ser que el de la derecha sea de algún sistema operativo diferente a windows porque SWING lastimosamente cambia su apariencia según el sistema operativo en el que se ejecute, suena tonto pero cada sistema operativo tiene sus particularidades en la  forma de implementar las ventanas cosa que JavaFX busco solucionar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambia dado el LookAndFeel o traducido literalmente "Ver y Sentir" de java.

Para revisar cuales tienes disponibles en tu versión de java prueba con esta clase:

```
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class MainClass {
  public static void main(String[] a) {
    UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo[] looks = UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels();
    for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo look : looks) {
      System.out.println(look.getClassName());
    }
  }
}
```

Cuando corres una aplicación java selecciona una por default, dependiendo del sistema operativo, y no sé que otras razones. Pero si quieres que siempre se vea igual tienes que seleccionar el LNF deseado.

La manera en que yo lo hago, por que hay varias formas, es de ponerlo en la propiedad del sistema, y eso lo hago "antes" de cargar cualquier componente swing así:

```
System.setProperty("swing.defaultlaf","javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
```

Aquí instruyo que se use el "NimbusLookAndFeel", que  obviamente viene en mi versión de java. Tú puedes seleccionar otro.

Prueba con los que te arroje la clase de arriba.

Te agrego un tutorial al respecto,

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html